# How do I convert MacOS C++ Program to 64bit?

Tags: 32bit-64bit

FinancesOSX is a program I wrote 10+ years ago in C++ for Macintosh. It broke when I attempted to recompile for 64 bit. There is a preprocessor error that the "Cocoa/Cocoa.h" file was not found, and a runtime error that it was unable to find the file "MacOSX 10.5.sdk."

Does anyone here have the skill and time to help me fix these problems?

Answer (score -1):

xCode finally worked on an older version of the software and automatically updated the C++ files to modern equivalents. The remaining few compiler errors were fairly easy to track down and correct. All seems well at the moment.